# Как сделать шрифтовую иконку из png

Tags: html, css, шрифты, icon

Есть изображение в формате PNG:

[image]

Как из него создать шрифтовую иконку?

Comment: http://fontello.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А чем существующие наборы типа Font-Awesome не устраивают? По делу: из растровых 
картинок иконки не делаются. Её нужно векторизировать в svg (я испоьзую Inskape), сделать черной, и уже потом создавать иконочный шрифт (использую https://icomoon.io/app/#/select)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-chrome"></i>
```

Comment: Мне нужна цветная иконка

Comment: В таком случае нужно найти или создать искомую иконку в svg формате и далее - создать иконочный шрифт. НО! цветные шрифтовые иконки не изменяют цвет средствами css, поэтому смысла в них особо нет.